# Is the sentence "the recipe requests to turn down the heat" correct?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Someone said that the verb "to request" is incorrect. Is this true?  But then, what verb should be used instead? Does this sentence sound awkward to a native speaker? If so, why?

Comment: It's okay in a way. Should be understood in the sense (or replaced with) "the recipe **requires** the heat to be turned down."

Comment: What preposition?

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is with the implication of the verb **request**.  A person (or object) *requesting* something is well aware that the request may be denied, and presumably has an alternate plan of action prepared in that event.

Inanimate objects may sometimes "request" things, but the implication that the request may go unsatisfied is an unusual one for an object to handle, so normally only thinking beings are allowed to "request" things in English.  Recipes would not be the type of object which would handle different responses to a request, which is why saying the recipe "requests" something sounds wrong to a native speaker: what would the recipe do if its reader said "no" in response? Instead, something like a recipe or a set of instructions or an assignment will "say" something (which does not require a response of any kind), or "instruct" something (which expects obedience and does not offer options in response to noncompliance).

Contrast to something like:

> The website requested his cell phone number, so Barry did not enroll.

Here, the software of the website does potentially have options, the most drastic of which is to prevent Barry from enrolling without a cell phone number (though it may choose to ask for a home phone number instead, etc - note that the important thing is that different responses are possible). But in most cases, inanimate objects cannot handle the possible rejection that requesting implies, so that verb is not used with them.

Note that sometimes the possible rejection of the request is merely a polite fiction (e.g. "The police requested that he accompany them to the station for further questioning"), but even when fictitious, the possible rejection is present.

Answer (score 1):

To my UK ears your phrase this sounds strange. As Greg Lee has said, **requests** sounds odd, I would use **says** or possibly **instructs**. But then further

> the recipe requests to

also seems wrong, even if a person, rather than a recipe, were making a request. We would normally give an object for the word requests:

> Billy requests that the heat be turned down

seems more natural. I am guessing this **to** / **that** switch is what you are asking about. The use of **that** forces us to make "the heat" be the target of our request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a recipe can request things, so I'd say the sentence is not good English.  A recipe can say things ("it says to turn down the heat as soon as the water boils"), so it would seem reasonable for it to request things, but it just doesn't sound right.

I don't see any prepositions in the sentence, so I don't know what to say about your question concerning the preposition.  What preposition?

Comment: Personification is quite acceptable. 'The notice asks people to take off their footwear'. But 'request' is, as you say, conveying a wrong flavour here. Making a polite suggestion is not the same as clinically giving an instruction. 'Would you now kindly simmer for 10 minutes.'

Answer (score 0):

We say "the law states" so it is possible for an abstract idea, in this case the law, to be a subject. However it does seem formal to use "requests" in this context.

If the sentence “the recipe requests to turn down the heat” is included as part of the recipe, then yes, that sounds rather clunky. A recipe is usually a set of instructions that people often don't follow 100%. If it would be prudent or cautious to turn the heat down, then perhaps just "it is advised/recommended to turn down the heat", or, more strongly worded, "it is necessary to turn down the heat".

Advise; to recommend as desirable, wise, prudent, etc.:
"He advised secrecy for the sake of national security".

Recommend; to represent or urge as advisable or expedient:
"to recommend caution".

Answer (score 0):

It does sound awkward - since a recipe is by definition a set of *directions* - "requesting" is too passive sounding. *"The recipe **specifies** to turn down the heat,"* is better, because it gives the recipe back it's authoritative status.

Answer (score -1):

Totally wrong. Request is a verb and the recipe cannot be a subject. therefore it is totally wrong. One of the possible correct sentence would be .... It is a requirement of the recipe to turn down the heat.

Comment: The recipe certainly can be a subject.  For example, one could say "the recipe requires the heat to be turned down".  The problem isn't that a recipe is not a subject, but rather the nature of the verb "request".

Comment: Let me be more clear that how the sentence is wrong. The word "request" is an infinitive, therefore cannot be used without an active subject. Example. You can say recipe "needs" but you cannot say recipe "goes". Although Both "need and go" are verbs however the verb need is bare infinitive and the verb "Go" is infinitive. the same way "request" is an infinitive and cannot be used without an active subject.